# Error while getting image from gallery in android

Tags: android, image-gallery, android-gallery

I know this this question was asked a lot but yeah it don't work for me :S 
I normally tried to use it but there always error messages.

Here is the thing I tried to import:

```
public boolean onMenuItemClicked(MenuScene pMenuScene, IMenuItem pMenuItem, float pMenuItemLocalX, float pMenuItemLocalY)
{
    switch(pMenuItem.getID())
    {
        case BACK:
            createMenuChildScene();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
            return true;
    }
}
```

For some reasone the startActivityForResult is red underlined if I change the name of the onActivityResult to on ActivityForResult on the code down here it's still red underlined.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

    switch(requestCode) { 
    case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                               selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Over here the get Content resolver does not work or is undefined :/
I have no Idea what I'm doing wrong :/

Answer (score 0):

You're trying image pick right?
the one you're using is outdated and works only for builds below KitKat.
i suggest you use document provider by google its faster and efficient and doest give OutOfMemory Errors.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html
also for your startActivityForResult should work normally, try File->Invalidate Caches and Select Invalidate Caches and Restart it should resolve all the unnecessary errors. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet.

In onActivityResult put this code when resultcode == Result_ok

```
case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

This solves your problem.